# Big Omega Notation. Am I doing this right?

Tags: big-o

If I have some algorithm that runs at best n time and at worst n^2 time, is it fair to say that the algorithm is Big Omega (n)?

Does this mean that the algorithm will run at least n (time)?
I am just not sure if I have the right idea here.

Thanks.

Comment: Algorithms are usually quoted as Big Oh in the worst case, so yours is O(n^2)

Comment: I mean if I wanted to use big Omega is this correct? Thats what I'm not sure about

Comment: Also, make sure you cast your vote on the answers you like and that you accept any answer that correctly answers your question. Make sure you do this for your older questions as well to encourage more answers.

Comment: No, it's fair to say it's Big Omega n^2, you always assume the worst with Big Oh.

Comment: Okay will do. And thanks for being helpful.

Comment: No worries, have fun! :)

Comment: And, as Jim Lewis points out: Big *Omega* is `f(n)` while Big *O* is `O(n^2)`. My comment mixes Big O and Big Omega, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Big Oh, you will state the worst time as the time it takes, in your case `O(n^2)`. For Big Omega, you state the smallest time, in this case `f(n)`.

Also see this [guide to Big O](http://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/) and this [discussion of Big O and Big Omega](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/big-o-big-omega-and-big-theta-106102/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If the runtime f(n) is asymptotically bounded below by g(n) = n, then f(n) is [BigOmega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)(n).

**Edit**: Most of the time, algorithms are analyzed in terms of their worst-case behavior -- 
which corresponds to "Big O" notation.  In your case, the runtime is O(n^2).

But for those rare occasions when you need to talk about a *lower* bound, or best
case behavior, "Big Omega" notation is used.  And in your case, the runtime
is *at least* n, so it is correct to describe it as BigOmega(n).